# Modifying the "Figure X" text

Tags: floats, captions

In LaTeX, it is usual to insert a figure with this structure:

```
\begin{figure*}[]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig1.eps}
    \caption{A two line caption}
    \label{the_label}
\end{figure*}
```

The text will compile that and insert a number for that figure in the text.

```
Figure 3. A two line caption
```

Now, I want to insert a word after the number for some **specific** figures.

```
Figure 3 (colorized). A two line caption
```

How can I do that? It is possible to insert the word after the caption. But I prefer to insert that after the number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure} (colorized)}
\caption{A two line caption}
```

probably works (depending what you what to happen in the list of figures)

Comment: This will affect also `\ref`.

Answer (score 7):

The *correct* way to do this is to use the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) and set a specific label separator that you can adjust to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,graphicx}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{colorized}{ (colorized): }
\begin{document}

See Figure~\ref{fig:first} and~\ref{fig:second}.

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \captionsetup{labelsep=colorized}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{A caption}\label{fig:first}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{A caption}\label{fig:second}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As can be seen above, the reference to the figures only include the figure numbers. A redefinition of `\thefigure` would also adjust the reference.